# Могу пропустить мысль, из-за чего окажусь(?) непонятым

Tags: грамматика

Запутался, как говорится, в трех соснах.

Дана фраза: 
*Я признаю, что могу **иногда** пропустить в разговоре мысль, которая мне кажется очевидной, из-за чего **окажусь** непонятым.*

Как тут с грамматикой?! Что-то меня останавливает. По семантике требуется скорее настоящее время (действие обычное, возобновляемое), но замена на "оказываюсь" дает что-то совсем уж косноязычное.

Не могу подобрать естественных аналогий.

*Могу заболеть, из-за чего не пойду в школу.*
*Могу соврать, поэтому промолчу.*
- Это все как-то по-другому смотрится... Нет аналогии, здесь неизбежное следствие второго из первого.

И даже переформулировать фразу не могу (хотя вопрос не в этом, мне интересна грамматика фразы как она есть).

UPD 15:04 17.01.2018

*Чтобы снять избыточные толкования, добавил в исходную фразу слово *"иногда"*. Надеюсь, теперь понятно, что вторая часть не будущее время (по смыслу) и не повторяющееся событие, а потенциальное.*

А чтобы "окажусь" ничем лишним не казалось вот вариант:

*Я признаю, что могу **иногда** пропустить в разговоре очевидную для меня мысль, из-за чего **попаду(?)** в неловкую ситуацию.*

Вопрос тот же. **Какое выбрать время и вид для "попаду", чтобы ситуация воспринималась потенциальной, а не реально повторяющейся.**

Comment: По-моему (точка зрения "любителя языка"),  "из-за чего" связывает два события; "могу пропустить" (сов. вид) говорит о будущей возможности, поэтому *окажусь* стоит в буд. вр.  Если написать "из-за этого", тогда речь пойдет не о событии, а о явлении: "из-за этого (явления) (часто) оказываюсь непонятым"

Comment: Спасибо, но речь-то изначально не о будущем времени, иначе и вопроса бы не было. Здесь **потенциальная** возможность такой ситуации... Может, она и в прошлом была. А "оказываюсь" не проходит, поскольку эта ситуация реализовавшаяся. как-то так.

Comment: "Могу (пропустить)" здесь не просто _потенциальную_ возможность описывает, а нечто реально повторяющееся время от времени, поэтому глагол настоящего времени "(порой) **оказываюсь**" здесь подходит - он тоже описывает повторяющееся законченное действие.

Comment: @М_Г Будущее время (могу завтра) здесь "не склеивается" из-за диссонанса с "кажется" - предложение и при таком смысле надо исправлять.

Comment: @Alex_ander - *а нечто реально повторяющееся время от времени* - это и плохо. Должно быть действие именно **потенциальное**. Причем в обеих частях фразы, во второй даже более, чем в первой.

Comment: Если потенциально, то  в этом же потенциальном смысле нужно говорить и о последствиях (**могу оказаться**) - иначе, после соотв. исправлений, воспринимается, что это _бывает_.

Comment: Если действие потенциальное, как указал автор, то и результат потенциальный. Таким образом, либо добавить второе *могу*, либо подвести все под общее *могу* (могу пропустить и оказаться)

Comment: @М_Г а вот со вторым (или общим) могу как-то не проходит. Почему - пока не понял. Какой-то другой смысл... "Могу оказываться" или "могу оказаться" вы предлагаете?

Comment: "Могу оказаться"

Answer (score 1):

Если здесь описывается хроническая рассеянность ("могу" в значении "временами, через раз в такое впадаю" - *настоящее время*), то можно либо  добавить второе "могу (оказаться)", - это подходит даже если говорится только о гипотетическом "пропускании мысли", - либо применить глагол *настоящего времени*:

> Я признаю, что могу пропустить в разговоре мысль, которая мне кажется
>   очевидной, из-за чего *могу оказаться* (порой *оказываюсь, остаюсь,
>   бываю* - если это уже случается) непонятым.
>
> Я признаю, что могу иногда пропустить в разговоре очевидную для меня
>   мысль, из-за чего **могу попасть** в неловкую ситуацию.

С сокращением второго *могу*:

> Я признаю, что могу иногда пропустить в разговоре очевидную для меня
>   мысль и **попасть** из-за этого в неловкую ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

1) Время в предложении 2

Можно сделать замену: Я признаю, что могу пропустить в разговоре **очевидную для меня мысль,**  из-за чего окажусь непонятым.

"Очевидная для меня мысль" и "мысль, которая кажется очевидной" ― это синонимы. На  время, которое обозначено в предложениях 1 и 3, предложение 2 не влияет.

2) Время в предложениях 1 и 3

Я могу пропустить в разговоре очевидную для меня мысль **(потенциальная возможность,** модальный глагол **в настоящем времени**).

...из-за чего окажусь непонятым.  Здесь **следствие реализации этой возможности**, отнесенное к **будущему времени**).

Comment: *На будущее время, которое обозначено в предложении, они не влияют.* - так вопрос как раз в том, уместно ли будущее время. Ваша замена вообще ни на что не влияет, на понимание грамматики - уж точно.

Comment: У меня грамматика этого предложения (время в предложениях 1 и З) не вызывает вопросов. И всё предложение, как мне кажется,  составлено правильно. Смысл такой: я могу пропустить  (пропущу) мысль, и тогда окажусь непонятым.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант ответа (основан на чувстве языка, а не на правилах).

Диссонанс здесь создаёт "я признаю". По смыслу предложения не совсем понятно, признаёте ли вы только первую часть или также то, что "оказываетесь непонятым". В первом случае лучше разделить предложение на два или использовать соединительный союз. Во втором случае "я признаю, что **окажусь** непонятым" звучит в другой модальности по сравнению с "я признаю, что **могу иногда** пропустить".

**Я признаю, что могу иногда пропустить в разговоре мысль, которая мне кажется очевидной, и из-за этого оказываюсь непонятым.**

Или вариант без "я признаю":

**Я  могу иногда пропустить в разговоре мысль, которая мне кажется очевидной, из-за чего оказываюсь непонятым.**

Здесь "оказываюсь" мне слух не режет.

Answer (score 0):

Я признаю, что иногда пропускаю в разговоре мысль, которая мне кажется очевидной, и из-за этого меня не понимают.